Monogamy of entanglement and Quantum Cryptography
I would like to understand thoroughly the monogamy of entanglement and its use in Quantum Cryptography.
The literal phrasing is that : "Whenever two systems A and B are maximally entangled, a third system C cannot be maximally entangled with either A or B".
Assume systems are qubits. Here is the circuit to generate the GHZ state :

The first step of the following circuit creates a Bell state :
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)\otimes |0\rangle
\end{equation}
The Bell state means that qubit A and B are maximally entangled. But none of them are yet entangled with qubit C.
However, the next step (another control X gate) just changes the state into :
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle + |111\rangle)
\end{equation}
This is another maximally entangled state, but between 3 qubits.
So, it is possible to create a state where C is maximally entangled with (AB), or any other combination between A,B and C.
However, if we trace out e.g. C :
\begin{equation}
\rho_{AB} =  \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle\langle 00| + |11\rangle\langle 11|)
\end{equation}
We get a mixed state which is no more entangled because it can be rewritten as a sum of separable states :
\begin{equation}
\rho_{AB} =  \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0| + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|)
\end{equation}
I think this is called a classical state because from a matrix point of view, there are only diagonal elements.
However, this state still implies some correlation for if one measures say B, it may get with equal probability either 0 or 1 and the state after measurement will be (i=0,1) :
\begin{equation}
(I\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)\rho_{AB}(I\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|)= |ii\rangle\langle ii|
\end{equation}
So if outcome of B is i, A will also be in state $|i\rangle$, which is just like if A and B were maximally entangled.
My understanding according to what I read is that the prior maximal entanglement between A and B is distributed equally between A and B, A and C, finally B and C. But then, this "entanglement" is less strong than the prior maximal entanglement between A and B, it is just classical correlation.
However, how do you differentiate quantum correlation (entanglement) and classical correlation ? Is there a simple example showing the former to be stronger than the latter ?
Finally, some quantum cryptographic protocols relies on this monogamy property. But I do not see how it guarantees secrecy because if a secret is shared between A and B, a third party C, who can access either qubit A or B, can still strongly correlate its qubit with A nd B. How does it work ?

Your formula 1 is the GHZ State. Are you familiar with this? There is also the W state, which is |001⟩+|010⟩+|100⟩. These are maximally entangled, but have different relationships remaining after measurement of one of the 3. Although maximally entangled initially, that entanglement does not remain in a known Bell state after. Otherwise, it would violate the monogamy restrictions.
